# Does the fact that $L_1L_2$ and $L_2L_1$ are both regular imply that at least one between $L_1$ and $L_2$ is regular?

Tags: automata, formal-languages, regular-language, context-free-grammar, regular-expressions

> Example: True or False : If $L_1$ and $L_2$ are languages such that
>   $L_2$ , $L_1L_2$ , and $L_2L_1$ are all regular, then $L_1$ must be
>   regular?
>
> False : consider $L_1=\{0^{2^i}\mid i>0\}$ and $L_2=\{0\}^*$

---

I know that regular languages are closed under intersection, union, kleen, complement property.  I also read that if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are languages such that
$L_2$ , $L_1\cup L_2$ , and $L_2\cap L_1$ are all regular, then $L_1$ need not be regular.

My question:

> If $L_1L_2$ and $L_2L_1$ are both regular, must one between $L_1$ and $L_2$ be regular?

Comment: Didn't you already give a counterexample? Or are you asking whether the fact that $L_1L_2$ and $L_2L_1$ are both regular implies that at least one between $L_1$ and $L_2$ is regular (which is a different thing)?

Comment: Thanks, you caught my actual question.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli, You are right, I think this is similar as : I also read that if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are languages such that
$L_2$ , $L_1\cup L_2$ , and $L_2\cap L_1$ are all regular, then $L_1$ need not be regular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is "no". Assume as a contradiction that it were true: the claim implies that every language $L$ such that $L^m$ is regular for some $m>0$ is regular itself.

In fact, call $t$ the least positive integer such that $L^t$ is regular. If $t\ge2$, use the claim on $L^{t}=L^{t-1}L=LL^{t-1}$ and derive a contradiction using minimality of $t$ and $t-1>0$.

But now, consider $L=\left\{0^{n^2}\,:\,n\in\Bbb N\right\}$. This is clearly not regular due to pumping lemma. However, $$L^4=\left\{0^{n^2+m^2+s^2+t^2}\,:\,n,m,s,t\in\Bbb N\right\}=\{0\}^*$$

Due to [Lagrange's four-square theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem).

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation.